# Using a ListBox to Navigate between records

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a `ListBox` in a form which has textBoxes bound to a table. The form is used for editing records.
I am not sure how to use the `ListBox` items to navigate between records. The action would be similar to how a split form works but in this case, instead of using a datasheet I am using a `ListBox`.

The following is my code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim sqlstr As String
sqlStr = "SELECT CustomerStreet, CustomerName, Address FROM tblCustomers ORDER BY CustomerName"
Me.SearchListBox.RowSource = sqlStr
End Sub

Private Sub SearchListBox_AfterUpdate()
Dim str As DAO.Recordset
Dim strRecord As Integer

Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
strRecord = rs.Fields("ID").Value

DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "frmEdit", acGoTo, strRecord

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RecordsetClone is only useful if you use FindFirst and Bookmark. Your code just uses first record ID. This will not correctly apply Offset argument.

The listbox needs ID field. That column can be hidden with 0 width. Typing first letter of an item will advance through listbox items. As is, user must type first letter of customer street not customer name. Since listbox RowSource is not dynamically filtered, could just include it in listbox design instead of setting with Load event. 
`SELECT ID, CustomerStreet, CustomerName, Address FROM tblCustomers ORDER BY CustomerName;`

If you want to go to a record as opposed to filtering the form, something like:

```
Private Sub SearchList_AfterUpdate()
With Me.RecordsetClone
   .FindFirst "ID=" & Me.SearchListBox
   If Not .NoMatch Then Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question and changed the `SearchList` to `SearchListBox` In the listbox property I have made the listbox  bound to one column. Then removed the RowSource from OnLoad event and added it to the listbox property. I did not know that I was supposed to Use SELECT * for the listbox RowSource and set the columns width which I don't want to see in the list to 0cm. Is that correct. It seems to be working now. Thanks you so much.

Comment: If answer resolves issue, could mark accepted and upvote is nice as well. Controls used to select/enter filter criteria should be UNBOUND - no ControlSource. So by 'bound' do you mean BoundColumn set to 1?

Comment: Yes BoundColumn set to 1